# IIS ARR Reverse Proxy Disk Cache

Tags: caching, iis, reverse-proxy, arr

I want to setup disk cache for reverse proxy responses for forwarded requests. I expect all requests to http://localhost:88/ to be forwarded to https://stackoverflow.com/ (as an example) with following rewrite rule:

```
<rule name="ReverseProxy1" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="https://stackoverflow.com/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Which works perfectly fine.

And I want all responses from https://stackoverflow.com/ to be cached on disk. I have following setup in applicationHost.config:

```
<diskCache scavengerInterval="00:05:00">
  <driveLocation path="C:\inetpub\temp\cache" maxUsage="0" />
  <compression enabled="true">
    <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true" />
  </compression>
  <sharedDriveLocation path="" />
</diskCache>
<proxy enabled="true" httpVersion="PassThrough" reverseRewriteHostInResponseHeaders="true">
  <cache requestConsolidationEnabled="true" queryStringHandling="Accept" validationInterval="00:01:00" />
</proxy>
<rewrite>
  <globalRules>
    <rule name="ARR_CacheControl_b17f5877-33f6-4bed-be49-f3c07a38cfef" enabled="true" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
      <match url="*" />
      <serverVariables>
        <set name="ARR_CACHE_CONTROL_OVERRIDE" value="1,max-age=1800" />
      </serverVariables>
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="stackoverflow.com" />
      </conditions>
    </rule>
  </globalRules>
</rewrite>
```

Unfortunately disk cache is never hit. I can tell it by examining IIS Log with X-ARR-CACHE-HIT=0 entries. And cache folder is always empty. The folder was created by IIS manager UI and I provided access rights to Application Pool identity to this folder, so I assume that the problem is not in access rights to cache folder.

Did I miss anything? Looking for a solution in internet didn't give me any results so any input is very appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out that the problem was that the Vary response header is present in SO response. And based on the reply on [IIS forums](http://forums.iis.net/t/1206930.aspx?ARR%20doesn%20t%20cache%20if%20vary%20header%20is%20set%20to%20Accept%20) ARR doesn't support caching when there is a Vary header in response.